Windows defender for Antivirus and Endpoint updates
We are planning to deploy defender for endpoint for our premises, the patch management solution which we are using is Ivanti to deploy the patches to windows 10 and 11 client machines.
I read from the MS article that below are the patches responsible for MDE updates in windows 10 and 11 machines
KB4052623 - Platform Updates,
KB2267602 - SIU and AV engine updates
Microsoft has provided the following update locations for signature update fallback order, I understand that we can define this update location in our Intune policy or GPO for the windows client machines to take the defender updates, but how these update locations are applicable for the environment who were using the third party solutions such as Ivanti to apply windows patches for windows 10 and windows 11 computers ?
what is the recommended approach to perform the platform updates, AV engine update and SIU for the environments who were using the third party patching solutions ?
Can we directly push these updates from third party patching solutions to the windows 10 and 11 devices ? OR the windows defender updates for Windows 10 and windows 11 machines should only be updated from either one of the update locations ?
KB4052623 - Platform Updates,
KB2267602 - SIU and AV engine
Updates Update locations :
Windows Server Update Service,
Microsoft Update,
File share,
Microsoft Configuration Manager,
Security intelligence updates and platform updates for Microsoft Defender Antivirus and other Microsoft anti-malware (formerly referred to as MMPC)

A) Have you read Ivanti's documentation on this? I found a few promising documents in a quick web search. B) Have you tested running Defender updates while the machine is managed by Ivanti? https://forums.ivanti.com/s/question/0D51B00005V3zi2SAB/how-to-installdeploy-windows-defender-updatespatches  https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/How-Windows-Defender-Engine-and-Platform-updates-are-detected https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/How-to-use-Patch-and-Compliance-Manager-to-Manage-Ivanti-Antivirus-and-Other-Antivirus-Vendor-Software

Hi, Thank you for for your response, Actually i am looking for the recommended approach for installing defender updates in windows 10 and 11, even though if any organization's were using third party patch management solutions for windows client machines. Should we need to allow the windows 10 and 11 machines to talk to internet directly to fetch from the updates from the location "Microsoft update" or as usual we can push these KB's to windows client machines through third party patch management solutions ?

We do specific solutions to specific problems on this site. Specific problems primarily on end user computing devices. Asking for "recommendations" and suggestions, and questions about enterprise architecture are often not on topic here. Further, you have a specific need not a general need. We do specific better than general, so asking specifics is a better thing for you to do.
